# How to execute the parsed command with jcommander?

Tags: java, command-line-interface, jcommander

I'm using [JCommander](http://jcommander.org/) to interact with the user on the command line.

The JCommander setup looks like the following:

```
JCommander jCommander = new JCommander();
jCommander.addCommand(new Command1());
jCommander.addCommand(new Command2());
jCommander.addCommand(new Command3());

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
jCommander.usage();
jCommander.parse(splitAsArgs(scanner.nextLine())));
```

Now I can use [getParsedCommand()](http://jcommander.org/apidocs/com/beust/jcommander/JCommander.html#getParsedCommand%28%29) to retrieve the name of the command being parsed.

My problem is that it seems very difficult to translate the returned String to the actual object that was passed to `addCommand`. I could hold a map externally, that does this kind of translation, but that is redundant since all this is already known by jcommander.

**How shall I translate from the name of the parsed command back to command object itself?**

Usually all my commands I pass to jcommander implement `Runnable` or something similiar. So if jcommander would allow me to access the object that was parsed, it would make my life much easier.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is the following:

```
String parsedCommand = jCommander.getParsedCommand();
JCommander parsedJCommander = jCommander.getCommands().get(parsedCommand);
Object commandObject = parsedJCommander.getObjects().get(0);
```

The `parsedJCommander` object has only a single command object, which in my case is the `Runnable` I would like to execute.